# Tensorflow - ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'ParseExample/ParseExample'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a `.tfrecords` file of the Ubuntu Dialog Corpus. I am trying to read in the whole dataset so that I can split the contexts and utterances into batches. Using `tf.parse_single_example` I was able to read in a single example. I tried using `tf.parse_example` but I get the following error

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'ParseExample/ParseExample' (op: 'ParseExample') with input shapes: [], [0], [], [], [], [], [], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0].
```

I am not sure what to make of it. The code I used to get to the error -

```
import tensorflow as tf    
TRAIN_FILE_TFREC = 'data/train.tfrecords'

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([TRAIN_FILE_TFREC])

reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

features = tf.parse_example(serialized_example, 
features = {
"context" : tf.FixedLenFeature([160], tf.int64),
"context_len" : tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64),
"utterance" : tf.FixedLenFeature([80], tf.int64),
"utterance_len" : tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64),
"label" : tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64)
})
```

Any ideas

Comment: You need to provide more details, preferably a small, self-contained example that exhibits the problem. You say that `parse_single_example` worked, but your code uses `parse_single_example`. Can you show the precise code that gives the error?

Comment: @PeterHawkins Changed the code. Had accidentally put in `parse_single_example` instead of `parse_example`

Answer (score 9):

to use tf.parse_example you need to first batch the examples:

```
batch = tf.train.batch([serialized_example], num_examples, capacity=num_examples)
parsed_examples = tf.parse_example(batch, feature_spec)
```

Comment: You may also find `parse_single_example` to work; in this case batches are not required.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem just now. Try putting brackets around the serialized_example to turn it into a list:

```
features = tf.parse_example([serialized_example], 
features = {
"context" : tf.FixedLenFeature([160], tf.int64),
"context_len" : tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64),
"utterance" : tf.FixedLenFeature([80], tf.int64),
"utterance_len" : tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64),
"label" : tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64)
})
```